# Fit curve from multiple measurements

Tags: python, curve-fitting

I have multiple measurements of a cooling curve. The problem is that the starting temperature for each of those curves is different. How can I fit a curve in python to this data in order to predict the cooling curve given the starting temperature?

As far as I can tell scipy.optimize.curve_fit would not work for this.

The data looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Pretty difficult to calculate a fit for a curve on an image - can you share some sample data? In principle, you could start by separating the cooling phases from the rest. That should be doable based on the first derivative (e.g. `np.gradient`). Then choose a suitable fit function and then move on with `scipy.optimize.curve_fit`...

Comment: I have the data seperated. Im just not good at plotting ^^. Also scipy curve_fit only accepts a single time series as far as I can tell. So I cant put in multiple measurements of the same series.

Comment: Seems like the ending temperature is pretty similar

Comment: Yes the ending temperature is always Identical. The start temperature is different though and the time it takes as well

Comment: did you try to multiple cool-down profiles (aligned e.g. by T_end) and calculate a fit for that?

Comment: What do you mean by that? Calculate multiple curve fits (one for each timeseries) and then try to match those up ? Seems like a good Idea. Will try that later

Comment: Sorry, missed a word there, I meant *merge* multiple cool-down profiles. My guess is that it is easier that way (calculate 1 fit from the merged data) instead of matching multiple fits. (align by T_min, interpolate to a common time resolution, calculate an average/weighted/etc. T for each time frame, calculate fit parameters for that merged T data).

Answer (score 0):

`scipy.curve_fit` might only take single values on the x-axis, but you could still do the trick by shifting the x-value for the first measurement by a miniscule amount, assuming that each replicate is equally weighted. So, the first measurement of replicate 1 starts at 0.0, the first measurement of replicate 2 starts at 0.0000001, the first measurement of replicate 3 starts at 0.0000002, etc.  That way you can fit multiple y-values for each x-value.